# require is not defined when using PouchDB filtered replication

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a bidirectional replication set up between PouchDB and CouchDB and I want to filter the replication so that only relevant documents end up in my local pouch.

```
pouchDB('medic').sync('http://localhost:5984/medic', {
  live: true,
  retry: true,
  filter: 'medic/doc_by_place'
});
```

When I execute the sync I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` from an anonymous function below.

```
(function () { return function(){return require("lib/app")["filters"]["doc_by_place"].apply(this, arguments);} })()
```

Where is this coming from and why is `require` not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming from the *to* side of the `sync` not the *from* side. Server side filters only make sense on *from* calls. To filter the *to* replication execute an [adhoc filter function](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#filtering-examples).

I ended up splitting the replication into two as below.

```
pouchDB('medic')
  .replicate.from('http://localhost:5984/medic', {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
    filter: 'medic/doc_by_place'
  });

pouchDB('medic')
  .replicate.to('http://localhost:5984/medic', {
    live: true,
    retry: true
  });
```